# Does a node require Change in sign of wave function

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orbitals

In a quantum Chemistry course we were asked to find the number of nodes of the wave function $$\Psi=\frac{\sin^2 x}{x^2} :  -3\pi \le x \le 3\pi$$ Clearly this has a removable discontinuity in x=0 so for a node it must satisfy the  equation $\Psi =0$ with $x\neq 0$ we get six solutions or six nodes.But I have also noticed that the hydrogenic wave functions seem to change their sign (phase) after each node.In this case $\Psi$ doesnt seem to change its sign,so can i say there are zero nodes!?

Comment: There is no sign change here because it is the square of (sin x)/x, i.e., the square of one of the two common sinc function definitions.

Comment: Yes you can say that a node without sign change is a node anyway. You won't encounter them often in real problems, though, because that would take an improbable coincidence.

Comment: More generally discontinuities are allowed in the wavefunction, but I believe that requires a non-continuous (step-wise) change in the potential.